# How to order a result of a sub-select with a case statement

Tags: sql, db2, subquery, case

I'm struggling trying to make this `SELECT` work without success. The sub-select is working fine, but I need to order the result with a case statement too, and I have no clue if it's even possible to do it.

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT TYPE, MAX(DATE) FROM  TABLE1 WHERE USER = '61616161N' GROUP BY TYPE 
ORDER BY MAX(DATE) DESC, TYPE)
GROUP BY STATUS
ORDER BY
CASE 
WHEN STATUS = 'REC' THEN 1 
WHEN STATUS  = 'LEI' THEN 2 
END
```

I don't know if I'm being specific enough, it would be nice if I can do it in one select like this one... it's ok too if this can be done with a workaround.

Comment: thanks for the edit.. im having problems even to format this :_\

Comment: Are 'REC' and 'LEI' the only possible values?

Comment: not the only possible but the only i want to evaluate in this case

Comment: What's the problem with the query posted?

Comment: Doesn't work, I forgot to post the code error but it was about sintax. I will do it tomorrow morning, sorry about that

Comment: My first thought is that your `ORDER BY` is assuming that the `STATUS` is going to be the same for every record. Is that correct?

Comment: What's the point of ordering the subselect results, if they are later reordered anyway? It doesn't make any sense semantically. `DISTINCT` there is also redundant in the presence of `GROUP BY`. You're also trying to group by a non-existent column `STATUS`.

Comment: thanks for all the answers, thanks a lot . 
the error output is "STATUS" is not valid in the context where it is used. SQL Code: -206, SQL State: 42703
im trying to pick the data from the subselect but ordered by status too, the problem is that i cant order status without a case statement, as i see it ..

Comment: @NocFenix Status will not be the same for every record, i need to pick first the ones with 'REC' on the result (sorry about my english by the way)

Comment: @mustaccio thanks for the advices, STATUS exists... but not on that context of course... distinct is for the TYPE column, that is not a key column and i just want to pick the last (on date) TYPE for that user ordered by STATUS, that cant be ordered without the statement , sorry if i couldnt explain it better on the post.

Answer (score 1):

You do not return the STATUS column from your inner SELECT so you cannot use it in the GROUP BY or ORDER BY clause.
Make the inner query return the STATUS column is the solution.

Comment: thank you, Michael, im starting to catch some of the errors i have, but still trying to do it on the right way, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you want, but the below will run -- is it was you want?

```
SELECT STATUS, MAX(TYPE), MAX(MDATE)
FROM (
  SELECT CASE 
           WHEN STATUS = 'REC' THEN 1 
           WHEN STATUS = 'LEI' THEN 2
           ELSE 3 
         END AS STATUS,
         TYPE,
         MDATE
  FROM (
    SELECT TYPE, MAX(DATE) AS MDATE 
    FROM  TABLE1 
    WHERE USER = '61616161N' 
    GROUP BY TYPE 
  ) X
) Y
GROUP BY STATUS
ORDER BY STATUS ASC,
```

Comment: "STATUS" is not valid in the context where it is used. SQL Code: -206, SQL State: 42703, thats the output for me , but thanks a lot for the answer, it gives me some perspective about what can i do

Comment: Sounds like you have a typo... did you type it exactly as I did?